# to prove that $f(x)=f(0)$

Tags: continuity

Let, $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function continuous at $x=0$ and given that $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$. 
Prove that, $f(x)=f(0)$ $\forall x\in(-1,1)$.
Ok. First give me some hint.

Comment: Hint first huh?

Comment: what did u say?   @Kaster

Comment: Hint: Suppose not.

Comment: Hint: $f(0.1) = f(0.01) = f(0.0001) = \dots =f(0)$.

Comment: Cancelled roughly twenty misplaced `$`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$f(x)=f(x^2)=f(x^4)=\ldots = f(x^{2^n})$$ where $n$ is any natural number

So if we let $n$ be infinitely large then, since $x\in (−1,1)$,
$x^{2^n}$ tends to $0$

Hence, $$f(x)=f(0)$$

Answer (score 8):

By induction we have
$$
f(x)=f(x^{2^n}) \quad \forall x \in (-1,1), \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Thus
$$
f(x)=\lim_nf(x^{2^n})=f(0) \quad \forall x \in (-1,1).
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: This can be done by contradiction, with a sequential characterization of continuity.

Comment: so in contrary there r two cases. right? first $f(x)$>$f(0)$? like this?

Comment: @Mathematics There's no reason to separate into cases.

Comment: So how shall we proceed? @T.Bongers

Comment: @Mathematics Think about the hint for a while.

Comment: Ok..Ok @T.Bongers